# Apache Thrift 0.15.0 compatibility with 0.13.0

Tags: java, thrift, backwards-compatibility

I'm upgrading my Apache Thrift from version 0.13.0 to 0.15.0 because of vulnerability CVE-2020-13949. But I need to comunicate with another system using Thrift that I'm not managing and couldn't upgrade to that new version. My question: Does the new version 0.15.0 have backwards compatibility with 0.13.0? And how to know about that, where could I ask for compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two answers to your first question

- **Wire format**: **Yes** it is backwards compatible, has not changed.
- **Source code**: There **may be breaking changes** depending on the target language(s) you are using.

And for the second part:

- [Apache Thrift mailing lists](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+thrift+mail)
- [Change log 0.15.0](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/CHANGES.md#0150)
- [Change log 0.14.2](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/CHANGES.md#0142)
- [Change log 0.14.1](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/CHANGES.md#0141)
- [Change log 0.14.0](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/CHANGES.md#0140)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! That was exactly what i need